# What is required to get a Flask app running on Github pages?

Tags: github, flask, github-pages

Recently I have been trying to create a personal website using a Flask app with Github pages. Once creating a repository titled .github.io and placing an a file titled index.html it will appear live at the address .github.io. However, once this file is deleted and replaced with a basic Flask application then a 404 page appears.

What is required to get a Flask app running on Github pages?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can't host a python application on Github pages, it's designed for simple static file hosting.  You could use something like [Flask-Frozen](https://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/) to turn your Flask application into static pages, but then you obviously have some big tradeoffs depending on your site's functionality.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what are these tradeoffs?

Comment: @PaulMcBurney many people use flask for Create, Read, Update, and Destroy apps (like how Stack Overflow allows you to create and update questions). When using static sites, you will not be able to accomplish this sort of functionality.

Comment: You can with a very hacky method