# The symbolic link /venv/bin/python targets a file which does not exist within your site's repository

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

For my Flask app, i'm trying to publish it on Github pages. However, when I tried to do this, it gave the error "The symbolic link /venv/bin/python targets a file which does not exist within your site's repository."

When I looked into this, I see that the vile /venv/bin/python points to the path
**/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3** which is where python is on my computer.

How do I fix this and make sure that github can actually publish my site and knows what the symbolic link is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Answer (score 1):

You can't host a Flask app on github pages.  It's designed strictly for static web pages.

[Flask app on Github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807039/flask-app-on-github-pages)