# The page isn't loading up on Github

Tags: flask, github-pages

I'm trying to turn my repo in a website for a school project and receiving this error:

> 404 File not found
>
> The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.
> If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
> For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

The link to my repo: https://github.com/NikitaLikhotvorik/final

It doesn't even have a custom URL yet but it does not load. And yes, I did select /root in Github Page branch settings

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us the actual url that is getting the 404 response...

Comment: Related to this from 2022: [Create a GitHub pages site using python and flask part 1](https://medium.com/@anupbhande/create-a-static-website-on-github-using-python-and-flask-framework-part-1-e26c0d39bec2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** I suggest that you move the `.html` and `.css` files to a `/docs` folder and target that folder in the build of GitHub pages.

---

As said in this documentation [About GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages):

> GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service that takes HTML, CSS,
> and JavaScript files straight from a repository on GitHub...

So GitHub pages presume that an `index.html` or a `README.md` file should exist in the root of the project (or the docs folder if you choose it) to show on the deployed page and in the root of your GitHub repo doesn't have either.

Comment: That helped but now it doesn't render my base.html which contains main design elements. Now it looks sth like that https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ADKXf3V2lv7Vk_Z2QE4Xx3Q9NLw5InF/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @FellowHumanPythonProgrammer Hi, take a look at this answer: [What is required to get a Flask app running on Github pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23808457/12542704), also, take a look at the comment that Jack moody made.